# Beginner To Programming

Tags: java, c++

I am in my second semester at my local college. My major is computer science and this is the second part of the Java course. The thing is, even though I passed with a C,(highest grade in the class) I want to do better and get where I need to be. Just like most people it was a up hill battle to learn because it was an online class and the teacher took an average of about a week to respond to anything. I am asking for techniques and tools that helped you be successful. We are learning JAVA and it's hard learning it on your own because there is no one to really look at your code. At the same time I am trying to learn C and C++ with what I've read from at Joel on Software. Any help is nice.

Thanks,

Orlando

Comment: What tutorials are you using above and beyond the online courseware?  Please **update** the question with the tutorials you're using or planning on using.

Comment: Be thankful you only have yourself to learn from. It will make you a better programmer in the long run.

Comment: @Marlon: What? I strongly Strongly STRONGLY disagree. Part of good code is making that code understandable to others.

Comment: Sorry for voting to close, but the question as stated is not much of a question. You might be luckier in http://programmers.stackexchange.com/, that being a more general forum.

Comment: Well the class was online and they only offered it online. The videos were of the teacher going over things during the video. Problem is that 80% of the time the videos did not work and he was all over the place. I've now come to the point where I am learning from a different book that I have bought and a site called thenewboston.com

Comment: @Billy ONeal Well. I'm 19 and I've taught myself almost everything I know and I would say that's a lot. I learn better from teaching myself than reading textbooks. Plus, having people spoon feed you is not such a great idea. Don't you think you learn better when you get your hands dirty?

Comment: This is probably a better question for [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).  (In fact there are several questions like this already over there).  This site is mainly intended to ask specific programming questions.

Comment: I'm 18. Ok British. I will keep that in mind. I'll go over there. This was the book we used first semester http://www.amazon.com/Java-Software-Solutions-Foundations-Program/dp/0321532058/ref=sr_1_fkmr1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1296605544&sr=8-1-fkmr1 this is the one we are using now:  http://www.amazon.com/Data-Structures-Abstraction-Design-Using/dp/0470128704/ref=sr_1_17?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1296605690&sr=1-17

Comment: BTW, @Orlando, once you get to actually start working on some code, if you run into problems then we are more than open to answer those here. Also, there's people in some of the chats (there's a link on the top of the screen) that will be willing to help with any doubts

Comment: There is a book, I think it's just called "Java Problems" (I'm sorry, a friend recommended it to me and I never got round to buying it).  It addresses lots of the quirks and features of java through interesting problem solving.  My friend swears that it made him a significantly more competent Java programmer and I've seen some pretty slick java programs he wrote.

Comment: @Marlon: You might teach yourself well, that's fine. But knowing is not the same as writing good code. If you want to consider your code good, having others look/comment is essential.

Answer (score 0):

I personally got a lot out of the [BlackBeltFactory](http://www.blackbeltfactory.com) Site. Not only for Java but for many other technologies. Give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

You can find some high quality resources for teaching yourself C++ linked from here:
https://sites.google.com/site/michaelsafyan/learn-to-code

I think C++ knowledge can be very easily applied to Java and can even be more helpful than learning Java directly. For example, it's hard to grasp the notion that some things are implicit pointers, without seeing passing objects by value, passing pointers by value, passing by reference, etc.

The key, though, to success is being curious, and writing small example programs that will answer your questions. If the textbook says such-and-such about the syntax or semantics, don't believe it for a moment (authors aren't always right, and programming languages may evolve more quickly than the books are published). Create a small, simple program that demonstrates the concept. Also, if you are forced to write it and correct mistakes when it fails to compile correctly, you are more likely to remember how the piece of code is written. It will also make you more familiar with and better able to understand the types of error messages that the compiler generates, if  you force yourself to write these examples.

Lastly, and this is particular an issue for learning Java where it is very easy to be spoiled, it's probably a good idea to use a simple editor instead of Eclipse or NetBeans when you first learn; NetBeans and Eclipse are awesome, because they incrementally compile your code, find errors, suggest fixes, and give you a simple magical button that will apply the suggested fixes. This is great for productivity and when writing code, but is really not so great for learning and remembering how to code correctly.